# Routing Emails to Office 365 Drop off Library then Email move to different Folders according to Subject

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, incoming-email

I need help routing email to Office 365 and then I need to move Emails to a different library according to rules set by Email Subject.

Comment: i found one way to achieve this requirement , using Custom Utility:- i created Utility and add all Rules in Custom list then i checked meta data with Rules List and then move to particular location